# Why does LinkedHashMap not implement SortedMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, sortedmap

LinkedHashMap is clearly an ordered Map. It orders based upon insertion.

So why does it not implement SortedMap?

Comment: "Ordered" and "sorted" don't really mean the same thing.

Comment: Because the language was built like that. If you want the implementation, you can subclass it and implement it yourself.

Comment: @JoeC can you be more specific? In what way do they differ from each other in this context?

Comment: @William Sorted means that the elements are soreted according to Çomparable or Comparator interface. A LinkedHashMap is ordered by insertion.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had always assumed that insertion order was just the default for LinkedHashMap and that you could provide a Comparator to sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order).

While sorted map is

> A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys. The map is
>   ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a
>   Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time.

So Boths exists for different purpose Where LinkedHashMap provides iteration in the same order of key insertion while SortedMap is for sorting using Comparator or Comparable